# KQL direct url to file + icon

Tags: 2010, development, search, kql

I have 2 questions regarding the KQL (keyword query):

1. Which property should I retrieve to get an URL to a file in results?
   The property `Path`"is `www.site.com/sites/site/documentlibrary/DispForm.aspx?ID=x`, clicking on it it will open an item, but I would like to open a file.
   So I need an URL: `www.site.com/sites/site/documentlibrary/file.doc`
2. How do I get the icon for that file so I could as well display it in gridview like in the search results?